# how to update existing databse to RTL?

Tags: node.js, odoo, arabic-support, rtlcss

there was a broblem with me to make odoo RTL in arabic langauge i solve it by instaling npm rtlcss , it working while creating a new database ,but the exixting on still LTR , how can update thr UI to make it appear RTL

Comment: getting same issue. Have you got solution?

Comment: Regenerate the assets bundle from the debug menu.